# Load data from two tables in the same query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to save myself from working harder, by altering my query command to include data from two tables in the same database in my SQL, and loading them into the same `datagrid` in my VB.Net project.

I have a query cmd in Management Studio that looks like this:

### Query that works

```html
SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, Val
FROM          PD_All_FT
WHERE         (DateAndTime = '2019-01-30 07:59:58.000') AND (Millitm = 597)
ORDER BY      DateAndTime DESC
```

*^Searching in my floating data values*

---

### Double query I want to work

But I would like it to search in both floating and string .dbo at the same time(same query)

In my head it would look something like this:

```html
SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, Val
FROM          PD_All_ST & PD_All_ST
WHERE         (DateAndTime = '2019-01-30 07:59:58.000') AND (Millitm = 597)
ORDER BY      DateAndTime DESC
```

*^Searching in both PD_All_FT & PD_All_ST at the same time, loading the data into the same dgv in my VB.Net project.*

---

### QUESTION

Is this even possible, or do I have to make two independent queries?

Comment: The question is unclear. Have you tried joining the two tables? This isn't a "double query", it's a query that uses two tables. Either you want to combine columns from both tables using JOINs or combine results using UNIONs

Comment: The tables are from the different databases or different instances? Sample data might help here also.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've tried joining them, but haven't got it working. The two tables are **PD_All_FT** & **PD_All_ST**. I want them to load into the same table for further use in my project.
I will try looking into the JOIN and UNION functions.

Comment: @EzLo They are from the same database, just two different tables, which I want to join/combine in the same table with a query cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result of the two tables combined using a "UNION" and then filter by your conditions.

You can do something like this:

```
;WITH PD_All_ST_AND_PD_All_FT AS
(
     SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, Val
     FROM          PD_All_ST

     UNION

     SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, CAST(Val AS VARCHAR(50)) AS Val
     FROM          PD_All_FT
)
SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, Val
FROM          PD_All_ST_AND_PD_All_FT
WHERE         (DateAndTime = '2019-01-30 07:59:58.000') AND (Millitm = 597)
```

Comment: Got your code working with som minor tweaks :) I've edited your post.

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to combine search based on data of two tables into single output grid:

```
SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, Val
FROM          PD_All_ST 
WHERE         (DateAndTime = '2019-01-30 07:59:58.000') AND (Millitm = 597)

UNION ALL

SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, CAST(Val as VARCHAR(50)) as Val 
FROM          PD_All_FT 
WHERE         (DateAndTime = '2019-01-30 07:59:58.000') AND (Millitm = 597)
ORDER BY      DateAndTime DESC
```

Also, you can choose another approach, based on a creation of view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.myView
AS
SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, Val
FROM          PD_All_ST 
UNION ALL    
SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, Val
FROM          PD_All_FT 
GO

-- and then simply replace PD_All_FT  with a name of a recently created view:

SELECT        DateAndTime, Millitm, TagIndex, Val
FROM          myView
WHERE         (DateAndTime = '2019-01-30 07:59:58.000') AND (Millitm = 597)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I keep getting error: Error converting data type varchar to float, trying your first example code.
I am no able to run the second code because of the CREATE VIEW function that it says is not supported.

Comment: Do you use Microsoft SQL Server? Can you run this: SELECT @@VERSION

Comment: I have adjusted first query with explicit CAST to prevent converting errors

Comment: Yes Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GD), but your edit made it work :D You just missed a round bracket at the CAST cmd. I've edited that now :) Thanks.